# Is it good or bad to use group in sudoers file instead of using user_aliases?

Tags: linux, sudo, group, pam, access-control

I have used user groups heavily while designing access control policies. I find user groups very convenient as it's very easy to implement with `PAM`.

Another reason I have organized the users with various groups is to implement (minimal) RBAC. But when I saw the `sudoers` file (of the company I am working for) I saw that it's consists of various `User_Alias` instead of using groups. I got the point of using `Command_Alias` or `Host_Alias` but my questions are,

- Why use `User_Alias` instead of `groups`?
- Is it good or bad to use groups instead of using the alias?

Comment: I would say that aliases are meant for a fine grained use of sudo, while groups are meant for systemwide linux access control.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `User_Alias` instead of `%group` when you want specific user to have more (or less) privileges, but there is no need for creating new group - it's just one user, or the user is there temporarily and creating specific group would be unnecessary, etc.
It's just another option how you can configure things in Linux. You can't go wrong with it.

Comment: First, IMHO fuzzy permissions don't work well for security. But there some exception could arise but in that case, I just could add that rule in the local sudoers file and then `#include sudoers.local` in global/central sudoers file.